# Umbraco 4-6: crucial jQuery attributes automatically removed from tag... Why?

Tags: jquery, umbraco, href

In Umbraco 6.X, some crucial jQuery attributes are automatically removed from all tags containing a `href="#"` ..etc...
Concrete example: 
when `<a href="#" class="big-link" data-animation="fade" data-reveal-id="1">` is pasted into Umbraco's HTML editor, the tag is automatically stripped down to just `<a href="#" class="big-link">` as soon as HTML is updated. Result is that jQuery effects + content won't work.
Poured through documentation with no leads.. Why might this be?

NOTE: THIS DOES NOT OCCUR ON MY localhost WORKING IN UMBRACO 4.9, ONLY IN DEV 
WORKING WITH UMBRACO 6... OBVIOUSLY NEEDS TO WORK IN DEV BEFORE GOING LIVE, BUT
CAN'T GO BACK TO 4.9 IN DEV.

Any and all insight would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You indicate some practical difficulty but surely a good dev environment should mirror the live environment.

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest! I agree with your comment, and actually thought about upgrading version 4.9 on my localhost to Umbraco 6 to better emulate DEV environment, however, my working knowledge of Umbraco, combined with intuition, are telling me some setting is behind this, not the version of Umbraco... hmmm....

Comment: Warpousa, sorry I can't offer any real help. Like others (so it seems), I don't know Umbraco, but I agree with your "setting" theory. My immediate reaction on reading the question was that it might well be a setting - probably an HTML validation setting - ie it seems to assume pre-HTML5 and strips out what it considers to be invalid HTML attributes accordingly. Is there a "Validate HTML Tags" or an "Allow HTML5" setting?

Comment: Any imput is better than no imput, and yes, it is almost surely a validation setting.  The Umbraco environment I'm working in has some rather ugly conventions with all kinds of .config files in the mix... A simple "Validate HTML tags" or "Allow HTML5" button in the GUI would be great, but no such luck!  Closest example I've found is encapsulated here: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/customizing-the-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor-(tinymce)/allow-any-markup-in-the-tinymce-editor   ... Still not quite my exact issue, but likely something along those lines... With thanks and regards, Warpousa

Comment: One potentially overlooked point on that umbraco wiki page is that you have to touch the `web.config` file before changes to other config files will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed in Dev… at least for now!  By accessing Data Types in the Developer console, I was able to set the Richtext editor (TinyMCE v3 wysiwyg by default) to ‘UltraSimpleEditor’ .  Suffice to say, the culprit here was indeed the wysiwyg editor (TinyMCE).  More specifically, editor was in fact stripping away crucial jQuery code contained in the tag even in its “pure” HTML source mode/view,  which it apparently wasn’t set to do on my localhost.  Per your recommendation, I would expect that touching the web.config file (and possibly other config files) in the future should help “tame” the Richtext editor’s URL conventions (which I’ll likely tinker with over the next few days – especially since the client, who doesn’t know HTML – and shouldn’t be expected to – may need to modify the two pages in question referencing the jQuery library used).  Thanks again for the input Mr. Beetroot-Beetroot and hope to cross paths again in the future!  Regards,  warpOusa